# onClick() doesn't work on JellyBean

Tags: android, button, onclick, onclicklistener

How i said in the title onClick event doesn't work with JellyBean devices.
Here there is the code

```
 ((Button)view.findViewById(R.id.more_questions)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LinearLayout linearLayout= (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.linear);


            EditText radioButton= new EditText(getContext());
            radioButton.setText("Inserisci la nuova domanda");
            radioButton.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
            domande.add(radioButton);


            linearLayout.addView(radioButton);

        }
    });
```

Can someone fix my problem?? Becouse with the higher api's Versions there isn't this problem

Comment: Can it work on other version?

Comment: i didn't get it what you are doing in this line view.findViewById(R.id.linear); where view is button as you have typecasted it

Comment: Simply i initialized a LinearLayout Object... in responding to @jfxu yes it work with the 22 and the higher api's versions

Comment: You should share logs if you are getting crash or error

Comment: No errors. It simply doesn't perform  click